# adaptive \ldots with no ("...") spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, punctuation

Due to the typographic traditions I'm used to, I prefer my `\ldots` to have no spacing in between, ideally exactly the same amount as in text. In math mode I would like to write things like `\(1, 2, \ldots, n\)` and have the spacing be adaptive:

- if the next character is a comma, I'd like something very thin like `\kern .08333em` (i.e., half of a `\thinspace`) afterwards;
- if there is an opening parenthesis ("(", "[", "{", ...) before or a closing parenthesis (")", "]", "}", ...) after the dots, there should be no or only tiny additional spacing (i.e., less than `\kern .08333em`);
- and whatever other adaptations of space *around* `\ldots` or `\dots` are normally produced by (La)TeX;
- *feel free to add other ideas*.

What is the best way of redefining `\ldots` for these purposes?

Comment: Please tell us how you are typing ellpsis in text and what packages you are loading.  In standard LaTeX the spacing between the dots in `\dots` and `\( \ldots \)` look the same for standard fonts, however the math and text definitions are different, with the text definition "misusing" `fontdim3`.  Similarly there are differences for the surrounding spacing that can be affected by packages.

Comment: @AndrewSwann In text, I usually type them as "..."; I work with `memoir`, `times-itsc` (like `times` but with small-caps in italics), `[T1]`-`fontenc`, `microtype`, `amsmath`, `hyperref` as the packages I would consider most important and of course a couple of others; hope that is useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\ldots` is using `\mathellipsis` for the dots. It could be redefined to use the text version, but the mixup of text and math fonts might not always a good idea.
`\mathellipsis` itself uses three dots as punctuation characters. That means, there is additional thin space between the dots. This can be changed by putting them into a subformula, then they are treated as `\mathord` atoms without additional space.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*{\mathellipsis}{%
  \mathinner{{\ldotp}{\ldotp}{\ldotp}}%
}
\begin{document}
$1,2,\ldots,3$
$(1,2,\ldots)$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Smaller spaces

Usually thin space is the smallest space in math mode, but to some degree `\ldots` can be adopted to smaller spaces:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\renewcommand*{\mathellipsis}{%
  \mathinner{{\ldotp}{\ldotp}{\ldotp}}%
}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@ldots}{%
  \LetLtxMacro\org@ldots\ldots
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\ldots}{%
    \ifmmode
      \expandafter\my@ldots
    \else
      \expandafter\textellipsis
    \fi
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\neghalfmskip}{%
  \nonscript\mskip-.5\muexpr\thinmuskip\relax%
}
\newcommand*{\my@ldots}{%
  \mathellipsis
  \@ifnextchar,\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar:\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar;\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar.\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar!\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar?\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar){\mskip-.5\muexpr\thinmuskip\relax}{% negative kerning
  }}}}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
$1,2,\ldots,3_{1,2,\ldots,3}$ (ldots)\\
$1,2,\mathellipsis,3_{1,2,\mathellipsis,3}$ (mathellipsis)\\
$(1,2,\ldots)_{(1,2,\ldots)}$ (ldots)\\
$(1,2,\mathellipsis)_{(1,2,\mathellipsis)}$ (mathellipsis)
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

TeX sets a thin space between inner atoms and punctuation chars in display and text style only, therefore the use of `\nonscript`. There is no space in case of the closing `)`, but because of the character shape, you probably want to have a negative kerning, this is applied in all math styles.

### More generalized detection of a closing delimiter

The example uses Andrew's hint of `\rightdelim@`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\renewcommand*{\mathellipsis}{%
  \mathinner{{\ldotp}{\ldotp}{\ldotp}}%
}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@ldots}{%
  \LetLtxMacro\org@ldots\ldots
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\ldots}{%
    \ifmmode
      \expandafter\my@ldots
    \else
      \expandafter\textellipsis
    \fi
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\neghalfmskip}{%
  \nonscript\mskip-.5\muexpr\thinmuskip\relax%
}
\newcommand*{\my@ldots}{%
  \mathellipsis
  \@ifnextchar,\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar:\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar;\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar.\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar!\neghalfmskip{%
  \@ifnextchar?\neghalfmskip{%
    \rightdelim@
    \ifgtest@
      \mskip-.5\muexpr\thinmuskip\relax% negative kerning
    \fi
  }}}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
$1,2,\ldots,3_{1,2,\ldots,3}$ (ldots)\\
$1,2,\mathellipsis,3_{1,2,\mathellipsis,3}$ (mathellipsis)\\
$(\neghalfmskip\ldots)_{(\neghalfmskip\ldots)}$ (neghalfmskip + ldots)\\
$(\ldots)_{(\ldots)}$ (ldots)\\
$(\mathellipsis)_{(\mathellipsis)}$ (mathellipsis)\\
$\{\ldots\}_{\{\ldots\}}$ (ldots)\\
$\{\mathellipsis\}_{\{\mathellipsis\}}$ (mathellipsis)
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

But for the detection of an opening delimiter before I do not see a way. There isn't a "`\lastmathatom`". Manually the space correction can be applied as the example file shows with `\neghalfmskip`.

Comment: This is a very nice solution.  Only one little quibble is that you have missed the other brackets from the original question.  As `amsmath.sty` is loaded you could use its `\rightdelim@` for detecting these.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks; actually I've clarified my parenthesis requirement/request and made the question (a tad) more general.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the hint with `\rightdelim@`. However for the detection of the opening delimiters I do not see a way, the execution time of `\ldots` is too late.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I made the `\rightdelim@` comment before the requirement on left brackets was included, and was just referring to `}`, `]` and the like.  I too do not see a simple way to deal with the left bracket.  The `\dots` command in `amsmath` only looks at the following token.  A complicated way would be a variation on the interal approach of `amsmath`, redefining all the appropriate left delimiter commands, this time to end with an extra control sequence after left delimiters.  But that would be a real mess.

Comment: @AndrewSwann (and Heiko:) In that case what brief command should I insert before the new `\ldots` for the (admittedly rare) case that it appears directly after an opening delimiter?

Comment: My latest example file shows such a use case that inserts `\neghalfmskip`. But feel free to use a better macro name.

Comment: Oh, actually I prefer it without the parenthesis-adjacent *negative* kerning, but anyways - this is all insightful.

Comment: In order to adapt your code to create thin parenthesis-adjacent positive kerning (which I assume also can be automatic for right parentheses and needs to be manual for left-parentheses), what commands should I use? Your line `\nonscript\mskip-.5\muexpr\thinmuskip\relax` suggests to me that things are trickier than simply using one `\kern` instruction.

Comment: @user14996 It is not clear, what you want.

Comment: What I meant is: how would I need to adapt your macro `\neghalfmskip` to get *positive* spacing next to parentheses? That is, a new macro `\halfmskip` to be invoked after the call to `\ifgtest@` (for right-parentheses) and also to be added manually (before `\ldots`) in case it's next to a left-parenthesis.

Comment: @user14996 I do not know, in which circumstances you need a positive spacing and what amount of the spacing you want. Perhaps it belongs to a new question.

Comment: I mean: same question, but with positive spacing next to parentheses. That is: Can I in your code simply replace the last occurrence of `\mskip-.5` by `\mskip.5`? I'm asking because I don't know what for example `\muexpr\thinmuskip` does - perhaps it's specific to negative spacing. (Also, positive spacing between "..." and parentheses was what my initial question asked about :-))

Comment: @user14996 `\muexpr\thinmuskip` is the mathematical equivalent of `\thinspace`, the negative spacing was just achieved by the minus sign. `\nonscript` means that the glue is not inserted in script and scriptscript styles.

Comment: As most compact is it recommended to use `$...$`?

Comment: @alper `$$...$$` for displayed equations should not be used in LaTeX. For inline math, both `$...$` and `\(...\)` can be used.