# a macro for mskip with half stretch and shrink?

Tags: macros, calculations, glue

We often find ourselves using nonzero stretch and shrink parts in `\hskip` and `\mskip`, typically 50% of the natural space value, e.g., `\hskip.1em plus.05em minus.05em` or `\mskip1mu plus.5mu minus.5mu`.  How do we automate the computation of the half? In other words, we need something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\mSkipWithHalfStretchAndHalfShrink}[1]{\mskip#1 plus.5#1 minus.5#1}% 50 per cent of the argument after plus and minus. The argument may be any integer or floating-point number.
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\(a\mSkipWithHalfStretchAndHalfShrink{20mu}b\)% expected to expand to \(a\mskip20mu plus10mu minus10mu b\)
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this produces the stretch and shrink parts of around 0.28–0.29 regardless of the integer argument.  Moreover, using a decimal point in the argument, such as in `\(a\mSkipWithHalfStretchAndHalfShrink{1.5mu}b\)`, throws an error.  We also tried stuff such as  `\mskip#1 plus\ratio{#1}{2} minus\ratio{#1}{2}` using the calc package, however, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this. With `\muexpr`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\mSkipWithHalfStretchAndHalfShrink}[1]{\mskip#1 plus .5\muexpr#1\relax minus.5\muexpr#1\relax\relax}% 50 per cent of the argument after plus and minus. The argument may be any integer or floating-point number.
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\(a\mSkipWithHalfStretchAndHalfShrink{20mu}b\)
\(a\mskip20mu plus10mu minus10mu b\)
\end{document}
```

The documentation is technically in `etex_man`, although in order to understand what is going on you need to understand the notations in the TeXbook really well.

By the way, it's recommended to add `\relax` to terminate a dimension expression explicitly. See exercise 27.4 in the book (although it seems safe in this case because `minus` is the last one already).
Here I add two because of the nesting.

Comment: Similar question but with dimexpr: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/doing-maths-with-distance-values-in-latex-source-code/11347#11347 -- muexpr is less used. I can find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77820/creating-implication-and-equivalence-symbols-of-intermediate-length/77825#77825 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75247/adaptive-ldots-with-no-spacing/75300#75300 that uses muexpr like that but I assume it's to remove the glue parts instead.

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows what we can do simply at TeX primitive level:

```
\def\hskipflex{\afterassignment\hskipflexA\dimen0=}
\def\hskipflexA{\hskip\dimen0 plus.5\dimen0 minus.5\dimen0 \relax}

\def\mskipflex{\afterassignment\mskipflexA\muskip0=}
\def\mskipflexA{\mskip 1\muskip0 plus.5\muskip0 minus.5\muskip0 \relax}

$x\mskipflex 10mu y$ %% does \mskip 10mu plus5mu minus5mu

a\hskipflex 1em b    %% does \hskip 1em plus.5em minus.5em

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used such specifications, let alone “often”, to be honest.

Here's the way:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\hspaceflex}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\hspace}{\hspace*}%
  {#2 plus \dimeval{#2/2} minus \dimeval{#2/2}}%
}

% there's no user level interface to \muskip_eval:n (yet)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_if_exist:NF \muskipeval { \cs_new_eq:NN \muskipeval \muskip_eval:n }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\mspaceflex}{m}{%
  \mspace{#1 plus \muskipeval{#1/2} minus \muskipeval{#1/2}}%
}
```

You call them as

```
\hspaceflex{1em}
\hspaceflex*{1em}
\mspaceflex{4mu}
```

Note that `\mspace` requires `amsmath`.

Comment: Thx! When writing “we often …”, I meant “me and my colleagues often …”.

Comment: Where do we get `\dimeval` from?

Comment: @GeekestGeek [calculations - \dimeval for pdflatex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652100/dimeval-for-pdflatex)

Comment: @AlbertNash Obviously so! Thanks.

Comment: Thx for fixing the typo!

Comment: If I don't care about the starred version, could I simplify `\hspaceflex` to `\newcommand{\hspaceflex}[1]{\hskip plus\dimeval{#1/2} minus\dimeval{#1/2}}` or rather `\newcommand{\hspaceflex}[1]{\hskip plus \dimeval{#1/2} minus \dimeval{#1/2}\relax}` or something else?

Comment: LaTeX as of 2022-06-01 complains that `\mspace` is undefined. Do you probably mean `\mskip#1 plus \muskipeval{#1/2} minus \muskipeval{#1/2}}`?

Comment: @AlbertNash Sorry, I presumed you are loading `amsmath`, which should always be done for math documents

Comment: @egreg I a full example (not in this MWE), I do load amsmath. Thanks for pointing it out! Would `\mskip#1 plus \muskipeval{#1/2} minus \muskipeval{#1/2}` work anyway?