# How do I get only two dots using \ldots

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I tried searching how to obtain only two dots with \ldots, but could not find it online. My aim is to achieve [a..b] to represent an interval of integers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

This seems OK..

It is just chaining \ldotp, which should give the same spacing as a standard ellipses.

See here: [adaptive \ldots with no ("...") spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75247/adaptive-ldots-with-no-spacing)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ldotsTwo}{%
  \mathinner{{\ldotp}{\ldotp}}%
}

\begin{document}

$[a\ldotsTwo b]$
\end{document}
```